# Is there anyway to authenticate the user type(user and Supplier) without any token in react and go with different page when I fetch the response api?

Tags: json, reactjs, authentication, redirect

is it anyway or solution that can authenticate the result in response JSON without any token authentication? My project have two type of user (user=1 and supplier=2). I need both of this user has different pages when they login to my system. The response JSON are as below:

[image]

This user is normal user will go to user page, while other user with user type of 2 will go to supplier page.

Here is my code:

```
login(){
  if(this.state.loginEmail && this.state.loginPassword){
    PostData('api/users/login', this.state).then ((result) => {
      let responseJSON = result;
      console.log(responseJSON)
      if(responseJSON.user){
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', responseJSON);
        // console.log("Home Page")
        this.setState({redirect: true});
      }else{
        console.log("Login Error")
        alert("wrong user credential")
      }
    });
  }
}
```

On the render component, when user login successfully I use redirect to go to Home page"/home":

```
render(){

    if(this.state.redirect){
      return (<Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/home',
        state: { loginEmail : this.state.loginEmail }}}/>)
    }
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("user")){
      return (<Redirect to ={'/home'}/>)
    }
    return (
    <div className="login-background">
    <div className = " login-form">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div className = "txtb">
        <input type="text" name="loginEmail" placeholder= "email" onChange={this.onChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className = "txtb">
        <input type="password" name="loginPassword" placeholder="password" onChange={this.onChange}/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" className="logbtn" onClick={this.login}/>
        <div className = "bottom-text">
          Dont have account? <a href = "/signUp">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    );
  }
```

What I want is when userType is equal to 2, they will go to supplier page "/supplier".

Comment: Yes, you can just call history.push() or history.replace() to navigate?

Comment: but how  to identify the different usertype as shown in JSON and push it to different pages? I mean if userType = 1, go to "/home", while userType = 2, go to "/supplier"

Comment: Just to clarify, the above screenshot, that is from `console.log(responseJSON)`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have already connected your component with react-router, this is how you can redirect your user to the respective paths based on the `userType`.

```
login(){
  if(this.state.loginEmail && this.state.loginPassword){
    PostData('api/users/login', this.state).then ((result) => {
      const { data: { user_info: { userType } } } = result;
      if (userType === 1) {
        history.push('/home');
      } else if (userType === 2) {
        history.push('/supplier')
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: but i get the error of "Unexpected use of 'history'"

Comment: Is your component connected to react-router? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter